# Detox test failed to run: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testEnvironmentOptions')

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, detox

I've been trying to run some detox tests on a react native app. These tests had been working up till recently. Now I am getting the error:
Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testEnvironmentOptions')

  11 |     // Can be safely removed, if you are content with the default value (=300000ms)
  12 |     this.initTimeout = 30000000;
> 13 |
     | ^
  14 |     // This takes care of generating status logs on a per-spec basis. By default, Jest only reports at file-level.
  15 |     // This is strictly optional.
  16 |     this.registerListeners({

  at new NodeEnvironment (../node_modules/jest-environment-node/build/index.js:96:49)
  at new DetoxCircusEnvironment (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest-circus/environment.js:27:5)
  at CustomDetoxEnvironment._createSuperInternal (environment.js:13:311)
  at new CustomDetoxEnvironment (environment.js:31:20)
  at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (../node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
  at async runJest (../node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)

14:09:34.503 detox[115576] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
I've tried updating jest, jest-expo, and jest-environment, as well as detox itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making all libraries with jest in their name the same version solved the problem. use `npm ls` to list them all out, and systematically make sure each have the same version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to have same version you can try this command with yarn install or npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).